# Gain information about expected return values count in function

Tags: python, function, return-value

I cannot find it anywhere but - can I in python function learn what return values are expected in the call? Like it will be so many output values at least.
Same as varying behavior of the function based on default args/varargs composition, but this time for outputs. For example, if existing function is growing to more outputs, but needs to support legacy calls accepting less outputs?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of what to expect from a function, you may be interested in pythons type hinting: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

like this:

```
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
return 'Hello ' + name
```

which does expect and return a string.

If I may give you a hint:
Don't alter the signature (amount and form of input and return values) of your functions.

If you need a new form of output, create a new function.
And as soon as your users may be expected to have moved on, mark the old one as deprecated in your docs and drop it one or two releases after.

Don't mess with your libraries users with functions that are called the same, but behave differently across versions without notice.